# Changing the behavior of UIBarButtonItem i.e shifting from action to segue and vice-a-versa

Tags: iphone, ios7, storyboard

I have a UIBarButtonItems, left side is edit and right side is add/done;

Now When edit is not clicked the action for right side button is to take me to next view controller and I have setup this using segue in storyboard.

However when edit is clicked I want to perform a different action i.e I don't want to go to that new view controller rather disable editing when clicked on that right side UIBarButtonItem.

Now I also have a IBAction done; which disables the editing.

But how to shift the behavior between add/done;

I can do this via programming; But since I have added the segue via storyboard, I wanted to know if there is a way I can switch between segue from storyboard and the IBAction in my controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you connect button action to perform specific segue. 
You can

- create segue between your controllers by ***Ctrl+dragging*** from one VC to another (not from specific view to view controller). You can do it easily in VC list window (to the left of your Storyboard scene). *Don't forget give IDs to your segues.*
- **connect** your button actions to VC action listeners
- in these listeners use your logic and **invoke** with specific identifier

  ```
  - (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
  ```

That's all!